# Daily builds for VIM

Tags: 12.04, ppa, vim

Is there any PPA that allows to be up to date with **the latest** changes in VIM, even they are buggy or not?

I would like to know that I use the **latest** VIM build even it is unstable.

---

Also, the following output can be useful:

```
$ apt-cache policy vim

vim:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
     2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 0
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to provide this at https://code.launchpad.net/~pkg-vim/+archive/ubuntu/vim-daily - although it is currently failing to build.

Comment: Cool! When you have a working version, please ping me and tell me how to use it. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău It's working already, but some recent changes to the packaging caused the builds to fail.  Should be good again after https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785221 is fixed.

Comment: Nice! I tried it and it updated my vim version.

Answer (score 3):

yes amigo we have one.

First uninstall , installed vim with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove vim
```

and then add the below PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dgadomski/vim-daily
```

then install it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

that will adds a [daily build PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dgadomski/+archive/vim-daily) of vim.

The last build was done 6 Hrs ago.

Comment: @Johnツ Actually the build for Precise was failed ,I have seen in the launchpad page : https://launchpad.net/~dgadomski/+archive/vim-daily/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me: I've followed your suggestions but newly installed vim is still 7.3.429.. I used PPAs many times before, so I know how to use it. But this one doesn't work for me. What could be wrong?